# Are there any examples of gods or people boasting of their ability to engage in multiple acts of sex in succession?

Tags: comparative, symbolism, concepts, nymphs, sex-magic

Are there any examples in mythologies of gods or people  boasting about their ability to engage in multiple acts of sex (multi-orgasmic) in succession? I am looking for examples in which they specify a number (as exaggerated as it may be).

*EDIT*: I should have specified that I am looking for examples in which the multiple acts are done with the same people, not with new partners. I am trying to exclude possible examples of the [Coolidge Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coolidge_effect).

Answer (score 5):

Heracles is said to have had intercourse with the 50 daughters of [Thespius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thespius) or Thestius in one night, all of whom bore him sons (Diodorus Siculus, [Library 4.29.3](https://archive.org/details/L303DiodorusSiculusLibraryOfHistoryII2.354.58/page/n447/mode/2up)) In another version, one daughter refused, making the number 49 (Pausanius, [Description of Greece 9.27.6](http://data.perseus.org/citations/urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0525.tlg001.perseus-eng1:9.27.6)).

However, in some less impressive versions, this took place over a week (Herodorus apud Athenaeus, [Deipnosophists 13.4](https://archive.org/details/deipnosophistsor03atheuoft/page/891/mode/1up)) or 50 nights (Pseudo-Apollodorus, [Library 2.4.10](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0548.tlg001.perseus-eng1:2.4.10); Tzetzes, [Chiliades 2.221](https://www.theoi.com/Text/TzetzesChiliades2.html)).

Comment: @b a it's a good start. But see my newly edited version of the question, which limits the question to exclude your example.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: MATURE CONTENT

The story of [Enkidu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enkidu) and [Shamhat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamhat) from *The Epic of Gilgamesh* comes to mind. Enkidu is considered a "wild man" in the sense that he lived alongside animals following his birth until the temple prostitute Shamhat was sent to "civilize" him through the act of love-making, after which Enkidu joins civilization and becomes best friends with Gilgamesh.

The part of the narrative that might interest you most is the specification of how many days in a row Enkidu and Shamhat engaged in sex.

The following is a passage from Tablet I of the Kovacs translation that describes the event.

> Then Shamhat saw him--a primitive, /
> a savage fellow from the depths of the wilderness! /
> "That is he, Shamhat! Release your clenched arms, /
> expose your sex so he can take in your voluptuousness. /
> Do not be restrained--take his energy! /
> When he sees you he will draw near to you. /
> Spread out your robe so he can lie upon you, /
> and perform for this primitive the task of womankind! /
> His animals, who grew up in his wilderness, will become alien to him, /
> and his lust will groan over you." /
> Shamhat unclutched her bosom, exposed her sex, and he took in her voluptuousness. /
> She was not restrained, but took his energy. /
> She spread out her robe and he lay upon her, /
> she performed for the primitive the task of womankind. /
> His lust groaned over her; /
> for six days and seven nights Enkidu stayed aroused, /
> and had intercourse with the harlot /
> until he was sated with her charms.

[Translated by Maureen Gallery Kovacs
Electronic Edition by Wolf Carnahan, I998](https://www.ancienttexts.org/library/mesopotamian/gilgamesh/tab1.htm)